# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, handle

When I run the app there is an Fatal exception error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //  get butten
        Button  bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        // set a monitor
        bt.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
    }

    class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener{
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
            String number = et.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel"+number));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Umm, what exactly is your question that you are asking? Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and revise your question.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, your device does not have an app that handles phone calls. It is probably a tablet. When coding, you have to code for such errors, by using try...catch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `Intent` by using a `context` & class name.

Since you haven't provide your Manifest file the easiest way to avoid the error is changing the code as follows

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
```

---

**More details from android Documentation**

```
android.content.Intent public Intent(android.content.Context packageContext, 
                                     java.lang.Class<?> cls)
```

> Create an intent for a specific component. All other fields (action, data, type, class) are
>   null, though they can be modified later with explicit calls. This
>   provides a convenient way to create an intent that is intended to
>   execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the system to
>   find an appropriate class for you; see setComponent for more
>   information on the repercussions of this.
>
> Parameters:   `packageContext` - A Context of the application package
>   implementing this class.   cls - The component class that is to be
>   used for the intent.